# How do I automatically evaluate an objective_plot after BayesSearchCV to find the *theoretical* optimal model?

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning, gaussian-process, xgboost-classifier

I did a hyper optimization for a `XGBClassifier` using `BayesSearchCV`. I increased the `kappa` parameter of the optimizer to increase the exploration of the search spaces by adding the parameter `optimizer_kwargs={'acq_func_kwargs': {"kappa": 6}}` to the `BayesSearchCV`.
I fed the `XGBClassifier` with a train and a validation data set.

When I look at the `objective_plot` I get the following picture:

[image: Output of objective_plot]

I can see that the optimizer can find some parameters that seem to perform better than others, like using `gblinear` as booster and using a low `learning_rate`. However, the best performing parameter set was a completely different one, as the red points demonstrate.

The thing is that the resulting model performs **consistently** better on my test data when I train a model with the parameters that perform best according to the `objective_plot`, *instead* of the best performing parameter set, which I can access via the `best_params_` property. Probably because the "best parameter" model is overfitting.
The theoretical calculated model seem much more trustworthy to me than the coincidentally "best performing" parameters.

So my question is: How can I automatize the process of evaluating the data, that are shown in the `objective_plot`, so that I receive parameters that are estimated to perform best according to the collected data? The optimizer must be able to calculate it, since it's the basic idea behind BayesSeachCV. But how can I access it?